# Vue: declared props in component are undefined

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've spent two days, trying to solve this issue by myself but couldn't get it to work. Basically I declared all my props in the parent component but for some reason they don't show up at all.

> Component

```js
let addFilter = {
    props: ['newFilterName'],
    template:  `<div class="row">
                    <div class="field-options">{{ newFilterName }}</div>
                </div>`,
};
```

> Instance

```js
let filterManager = new Vue({
    el: '#filter-manager',
    components: {
        'add-filter': addFilter
    },
    data: {
        newFilterName: 'Test1234'
    }
});
```

> HTML

```html
<div id="filter-manager" v-show="visible">
    <div class="body">
        <add-filter></add-filter>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass the data from the parent to the component

```
<div id="filter-manager" v-show="visible">
    <div class="body">
        <add-filter :new-filter-name="newFilterName" ></add-filter>
     </div>
</div>
```

To be clear `:new-filter-name` is the property of the child component and the right side `"newFilterName"` is the data property you defined in the parent. Just naming them the same doesn't do anything. You need the assignment when you instantiate the component.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It does work now. Just one more humble ask maybe you could change your answer to `<add-filter :new-filter-name="newFilterName" ></add-filter>` so I can accepted.

Comment: Yes Justin, you are right `:new-filter-name` and `:newFilterName ` both work.